Как сделать отправление сообщения в чат боте, только после ответа?
Прошу помочь с кодом на питоне. Я использую «botfather” в «теллеграме». И мне нужно сделать такое действие:
Пока сообщение не пришло: True (т.е. ничего не делать).
